# Unsupported LaTex causing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, latex, mathjax

I am using this library in app-level build.gradle:

```
implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
```

XML code:

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
                            android:id="@+id/math0"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            auto:engine="MathJax"
                            auto:text="" />
```

Java code:

```
((MathView) lloption.findViewById(R.id.math0)).setText(txt);
```

I tried other LaTex equations. They are working perfectly. But for some reason, this LaTex is not working: L i^{+}
Kindly suggest how to fix this:

```
Logs shown are:
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.providers.TemplateProvider.parseEmbeddedExtension(TemplateProvider.java:117)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.providers.TemplateProvider.resourceName(TemplateProvider.java:91)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.providers.TemplateProvider.loadItemDoc(TemplateProvider.java:80)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.providers.TemplateProvider.getSnippet(TemplateProvider.java:43)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.providers.TemplateProvider.provides(TemplateProvider.java:29)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Theme.getSnippet(Theme.java:194)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.altFetch(Chunk.java:955)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.altFetch(Chunk.java:858)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk._resolveTagValue(Chunk.java:1038)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.resolveTagValue(Chunk.java:1009)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.SnippetTag.render(SnippetTag.java:43)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Snippet.render(Snippet.java:843)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.SnippetTag.render(SnippetTag.java:50)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Snippet.render(Snippet.java:843)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.explodeToPrinter(Chunk.java:728)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.renderForParentToPrinter(Chunk.java:689)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.explodeForParentToPrinter(Chunk.java:681)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.render(Chunk.java:643)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.x5.template.Chunk.toString(Chunk.java:612)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.014 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at io.github.kexanie.library.MathView.setText(MathView.java:69)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.edudigm.eklavya.activities.MockExamActivity.addOptions(MockExamActivity.java:472)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.edudigm.eklavya.activities.MockExamActivity.access$2000(MockExamActivity.java:66)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.edudigm.eklavya.activities.MockExamActivity$14.onResponse(MockExamActivity.java:1017)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:82)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    2021-09-12 19:54:26.015 29469-29469/com.edudigm.eklavya W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```